# Overlay Text on ImageView(Thumbnail) in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview

I am a newbie to Android and I am developing an app that draw thumbnail of video on ImageView widget, this has been easily done.Code for creating Thumbnail:

```
       ImageView thumbnail1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

       thumbnail1.setClickable(true);
       Bitmap bmThumbnail1;// bmThumbnail2, bmThumbnail3 ;

       // MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail 
       bmThumbnail1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 
                      Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

      thumbnail1.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail1);
```

But what else I want is that to overlay a play button or atleast have a TextView over Thumbnail where I can setText of name of video that will be displayed over Thumbnail whenever touched(for Touchscreen) or whenever hovered(for typical Desktop/PC).
How to accomplish this.?

Please Help...

Thanx in advance

Comment: use a relative layout and place a textview over the image

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own layout to arrange items in the way you need, this is an example of a layout showing the Image and on the bottom of it center the title that you want, you create an xml file in your layouts folder name it as you want and set this code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/yourImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/yourImageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Once you have it stored you can use the LayoutInflater to make an instance of that layout and then populate the items accordingly to your needs as shown below:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.id.yourXML, null);
ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourText);
//And starting from here, you can do just set the image and text...
```

Regards!